# Reloading Data Without Retaining Success/Error State in Angular App

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm working on an Angular application that involves editing and updating posts. When a user navigates away from the edit post page and returns, the data and success/error state are retained. I want to set the success/error state messages to null when the user returns to the page to ensure they see the latest post content without any success or error messages from previous submissions. How can I achieve this?

Code snippets for reference:

EditPostPageComponent - Component for the edit post page.
Contains the form and subscribes to the state for success and error messages.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';

import { UpdatePostData } from '@client-app/user/models';
import * as fromUser from '@client-app/user/reducers';
import { PostsPageActions } from '@client-app/user/actions';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-post-page',
  template: `
    <app-edit-post-form
      (submitted)="onSubmit($event)"
      [pending]="(pending$ | async)!"
      [errorMessage]="error$ | async"
      [successMessage]="success$ | async"
    ></app-edit-post-form>
  `,
  styles: [],
})
export class EditPostPageComponent implements OnInit {
  pending$ = this.store.select(fromUser.selectUpdatePostPagePending);
  error$ = this.store.select(fromUser.selectUpdatePostPageError);
  success$ = this.store.select(fromUser.selectUpdateSuccessMsg);

  constructor(private store: Store) {}

  onSubmit(event: { postId: string; formData: UpdatePostData }) {
    this.store.dispatch(
      PostsPageActions.updatePost({
        postId: event.postId,
        updatePostData: event.formData,
      })
    );
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

EditPostFormComponent - Component for the edit post form. Subscribes to the post$ observable and sets form values accordingly.

```
import {
  Component,
  Input,
  Output,
  EventEmitter,
  OnDestroy,
} from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

import * as fromUser from '@client-app/user/reducers';
import { Post, UpdatePostData } from '@client-app/user/models';
import { UserPostPageActions } from '@client-app/user/actions';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-post-form',
  template: `
    <mat-card>
      <mat-card-title>Edit post</mat-card-title>
      <mat-card-content>
        <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
          <p>
            <mat-form-field>
              <textarea
                matInput
                placeholder="Description"
                formControlName="description"
              ></textarea>
            </mat-form-field>
          </p>
          <p>
            <mat-form-field>
              <input
                type="text"
                matInput
                placeholder="Location"
                formControlName="location"
              />
            </mat-form-field>
          </p>
          <p>
            <mat-form-field>
              <input
                type="text"
                matInput
                placeholder="Mood"
                formControlName="mood"
              />
            </mat-form-field>
          </p>
          <p>
            <mat-form-field>
              <input
                type="text"
                matInput
                placeholder="Weather"
                formControlName="weather"
              />
            </mat-form-field>
          </p>
          <p>
            <mat-checkbox formControlName="isPublic">Public</mat-checkbox>
          </p>
          <p
            *ngIf="errorMessage || successMessage"
            class="edit-post-message"
            [ngClass]="{
              'edit-post-error': errorMessage,
              'edit-post-success': successMessage
            }"
          >
            {{ errorMessage || successMessage }}
          </p>
          <div class="edit-post-buttons">
            <button
              type="submit"
              mat-raised-button
              color="primary"
              [disabled]="disabled"
            >
              Save
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      :host {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        margin: 4.5rem 0;
      }

      mat-card-title {
        text-align: center;
        margin: 1rem 0;
      }

      mat-card-content {
        min-width: 300px;
      }

      mat-form-field {
        width: 100%;
      }

      .edit-post-message {
        padding: 1rem;
        color: white;
      }

      .edit-post-error {
        background-color: red;
      }

      .edit-post-success {
        background-color: green;
      }

      .edit-post-buttons {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
      }
    `,
  ],
})
export class EditPostFormComponent implements OnDestroy {
  @Input() pending!: boolean;
  @Input() errorMessage!: string | null;
  @Input() successMessage!: string | null;
  @Output() submitted = new EventEmitter<{
    postId: string;
    formData: UpdatePostData;
  }>();

  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    description: new FormControl(''),
    location: new FormControl(''),
    mood: new FormControl(''),
    weather: new FormControl(''),
    isPublic: new FormControl(true),
  });

  private postId!: string;
  private destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

  post$: Observable<Post>;

  disabled: boolean = false;

  constructor(private store: Store, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.post$ = store.select(fromUser.selectUserPost);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Accessing URL parameters
    this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
      this.postId = params['postId'];
    });

    this.store.dispatch(UserPostPageActions.enter({ postId: this.postId }));

    // Subscribe to the post$ observable and set form values when data is received
    this.post$.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe((post) => {
      if (post) {
        this.form.patchValue({
          description: post.description,
          location: post.location,
          mood: post.mood,
          weather: post.weather,
          isPublic: post.isPublic,
        });
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }

  submit() {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      const formData: UpdatePostData = this.form.value;
      this.submitted.emit({ postId: this.postId, formData });
      this.form.reset();
      this.disabled = true;
    }
  }

  // Disable/Enable form when 'pending' changes
  ngOnChanges(): void {
    if (this.pending) {
      this.form.disable();
    } else {
      this.form.enable();
    }
  }
}
```

[Additional description and context](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/handling-error-states-with-ngrx-6b16f6d12a08)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create an action to reset the state to its initial value.
This action can be dispatched when the form is opened, or when the form is closed.

As a side note: maybe this state doesn't need to be stored in the global store. It's fine to keep state local in the component store.